# Apache high CPU usage but medium overall CPU usage

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, cpu-usage

I am running a website on an Apache server. The server itself is an 8 core server with 35G RAM. I am monitoring the statistics of the apache resource usage and the overall server resource usage.

I noticed the CPU usage of apache actually goes over 100%, even up to 150%! How is this possible?

Looking at my overall CPU utilization across all my CPUs, it is only around 0.3.

Currently, from Google Analytic, there is around 400 users viewing the website simultaneously. I am also browsing the site and refreshing pages just to test, everything seems smooth.

So my question is, is this apache CPU usage stats something I need to be worried about?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, the CPU usage of process can go upto (100 x no. of cores)%. If you're worried about performance and want to peek under Apache's hood, try to use gdb as explained in this guide: http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html

Comment: You're not wrong about the CPU usage. But using mod_status to get a better picture of what's going on inside your webserver is a lot less invasive / effort than using strace / gdb etc.